# Make cursor jump to same row, different column when pressing Enter, with other specific requirements

Tags: excel, vba, mouse-cursor

I've had a look about and whilst I've found some similar threads (with varying degrees of relevancy/usefulness), none of them covered my exact situation.

I want to use a sheet in my workbook as a form where I input one type of data in one column and press enter, and then jump to another column on the same row to input a second type of data.

My sheet has an "Item Number" column and a "Count" column with several columns in between them.

What I'm trying to achieve is:

- Type data into a cell in the "Item Number" column and press Enter.
- The cursor appears on the same row, several columns to the right in the "Count" column.

I want this only to occur when pressing Enter ***after*** entering data into ***blank cells only***
in the "Item Number" column. Pressing Enter in any other column should just allow the cursor to behave as it would otherwise.

At the moment I have the code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Range("A100") = ActiveCell.Address
Cells(Application.ActiveCell.Row, 11).Select

End Sub
```

The first line (beginning with "Range") allows me to see the active cell address in cell A100. This works along with some other code that lets me colour fill the active cell in that worksheet so I can see things a bit better when the spreadsheet gets busy.

The second line (beginning with "Cells") is the code that is ***supposed*** to make the cursor jump over to the "Count" column after pressing Enter in the "Item Number" column.

Now, this all works fine except for one major drawback.....
When clicking on a cell in the "Item Number" column, the cursor is immediately moved to the "Count" column before I'm able to enter any data, let alone hit the Enter key.

What am I doing wrong?
and
How do I go about ensuring this ***only*** happens when pressing Enter ***after*** entering data into a ***blank*** cell in the "Item Number" column?

I hope this makes sense, reading so much about code has got me cross eyed.
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should combine `Worksheet_Change()` and `Worksheet_SelectionChange()` events and use a sheet scoped variable to check for empty cells being changed

```
Option Explicit

Dim emptyCell As Boolean

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub ' don't bother nulticell selections
    If Cells(1, Target.Column).Value <> "Item Number" Then Exit Sub ' don't bother selections outside "Item Number" column
    If emptyCell And Not IsEmpty(Target.Value) Then Cells(Target.Row, Range("A1", Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Find(what:="Count", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).Column).Select ' if current cell was empty and now it is not then skip to "Count" column same row
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    emptyCell = IsEmpty(Target.Value) ' store the info about current selection being empty
End Sub
```

Comment: That code now works as it should but only on its own. When I add other code in the VBA window for that sheet then it all seems to break down. Should I stick this in a new thread as it's become another problem, or carry on with it here?

Comment: yes, make a new questiona and add all what strictly necessary to have people understand the specific goal

Comment: Thank you, will do :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the *Change* event. The code below should do what you want. It could be expanded to respond (differently) to changes in other columns.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const TriggerColumn As Long = 3             ' modify as required
    Const NextColumn As Long = 11               ' modify as required

    Dim Rng As Range

    ' don't take action if more than 1 cell was changed
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

    ' don't include the caption row in ther ange
    ' find the last used row in a column filled BEFORE Triggercolumn
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(2, TriggerColumn), Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))

    ' take action only if the changed cell is within Rng
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Rng) Is Nothing Then
        ' skip if the change resulted in a blank cell
        With Target
            If Len(.Value) Then
                Cells(.Row, NextColumn).Select
            Else
                ' prevent the next action from triggering this function
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                ' delete contents of the next cell
                Cells(.Row, NextColumn).ClearContents
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```